# Regex - how to avoid matching a pattern if its inside a URL

Tags: .net, regex, url

Trying to get all variables that starts with % and followed by a single digit

eg: `%1`

I'm currently using %[0-9] or %\d

But in the content which I'm searching there are some URL having those variables

eg: `http://www.myurl.com/exe/ao1/rss.php?search=%0`

```
http://www.myurl.com/tab/site/var/%0/%1/guestbook/go
```

Would they be a pattern where I could search all the %\d patterns except in a URL form string?

Comment: Easiest way is to remove URLs first.

Comment: Maybe try using `/(%\d+)`...

Comment: What is the regex flavor? In .NET, you can just check it with a look-behind: [`(?<!\bhttp?://\S*)%\d(?!\d)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c!%5cbhttp%3f%3a%2f%2f%5cS*)%25%5cd(%3f!%5cd)&i=http%3a%2f%2fwww.myurl.com%2ftab%2fsite%2fvar%2f%250%2f%251%2fguestbook%2fgo%0d%0a%0d%0aAge%3a+%251%0d%0aName%3a+%2512).

Comment: @stribizhev Thankyou! your pattern worked!!!!!!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you describe a highr picture of your goal? Maybe regex is not actually the better solution (I think about parsing html especially)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET, you can just check it with a variable-width look-behind:

```
(?<!\bhttps?://\S*)%\d(?!\d)
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c!%5cbhttps%3f%3a%2f%2f%5cS*)%25%5cd(%3f!%5cd)&i=http%3a%2f%2fwww.myurl.com%2ftab%2fsite%2fvar%2f%250%2f%251%2fguestbook%2fgo%0d%0a%0d%0aAge%3a+%251%0d%0aName%3a+%2512)

The regex means:

- `(?<!\bhttps?://\S*)` - check if there is no `http://` or `https://` in front with any number of non-whitespace symbols following it
- `%\d` - match `%` and a digit...
- `(?!\d)` - but only if not followed by a digit.

Answer (score 0):

Embed this regex with yours regex. This will cut all the URl and you can get your result

```
"<^(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]>"
```